# Is there any way to bind jump and ski to space?

Tags: tribes-ascend

I'm a Tribes vet. Naturally I don't want jump on control and ski on space. I want them both on space. Skiing was originally an undocumented feature so they both functioned on the same key (space). Is there any way to put them both on space?

Comment: Consider posting your edit as an answer - if you had this question, surely others did too, and if you put it as an answer, you'll be able to accept it (yay) *and* get upvotes on it (doubleyay)!

Comment: @Raven Ah thank you kindly. I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's actually a jump/ski bind in the options.

Comment: As someone who did not play Tribes 2, I'm curious:  If you're running along and hit the jump/ski bind, do you jump?  Or Ski?  How does having them together help?

Comment: @GWLlosa You jump when hitting space and then if you hold it you'll ski when you land.